# How to Get App Name

Tags: apex

Is it possible to get an App's name (not just the label) in Apex? I looked into `DescribeTabs()` but that doesn't seem to give me the name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can query the Applications in an org via the [AppMenuItem](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_objects_appmenuitem.htm) object.

> SELECT Id, Name, Label FROM AppMenuItem

Answer (score -2):

```
<script>
    var myappname = document.getElementById("tsidLabel").innerText;

    Visualforce.remoting.Manager.invokeAction('{!$RemoteAction.Appname.getAppname}', myappname,
        function(result, event){
            if (event.status) {
            } else if (event.type === 'exception') {
                document.getElementById("responseErrors").innerHTML = event.message + "<br/>\n<pre>" + event.where + "</pre>";
            } else {
                document.getElementById("responseErrors").innerHTML = event.message;
            }
        },
        {escape: true}
    );
</script>
```

**Class:**

```
global with sharing class Appname {
    @RemoteAction
    global static string getAppname(String appName) {
        system.debug('app name'+appname);
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please update this answer to include more information than simply a link. If the link becomes invalid for some reason, the meaning of this answer will be lost. You should at least provide a summary of the details of the content of the link, preferably with some code samples, etc.